# Require all fields of a given type to be annotated by a certain field annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have a nice field annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Foo {
    // lots of useful, mandatory values here
}
```

and I would like to create a type annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface Bar {
    ...
}
```

such that any types annotated `@Bar` will throw compiler warnings if they contain fields that are not annotated with `@Foo.`

In other words, I would like `Bar` to enforce a contract in which all of the `@Bar`-annotated class' fields *must* have a `@Foo` annotation, otherwise I will get a nice warning from my compiler.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no annotation that makes javac do that directly.

However, there are things called 'annotation processors'. They run as part of a compilation run, and they can generate errors and warnings. You can write one, having it trigger on any source file containing type(s) annotated with `@Bar`, inspecting each field inside, and emitting errors if you find any without a `@Foo` annotation.

Annotation Processors can work on annotations with any retention level.